# All figures at end of section (or Chapter) but in the order they were cited in the text

Tags: sectioning, floats, cross-referencing

I've been trying to do this for so long, it would make my life so much easier.

I have a `*.tex` file containing all the details of the figures in a chapter (but not necessarily in the right order), because the first thing I do when I'm writing is make all the figures, but I don't know what order I'll need them.

Then I want to be able to reference this file at a particular point so I insert:

```
\input{figures.tex}
```

and all the figures appear, and that's great, but the thing is, I want them to be ordered by the location that they are first cited in the text, because I make the figures first, and I'm not sure what order I will use them.

Up till now I end up scouring the document finding the references and ordering the figure order at the end manually, but this isn't very efficient.

Alternatively can anyone suggest another workflow/method that would enable me to achieve something similar. (like maybe inserting the figures at a particular place but them only appearing at the end in a section I designate) Cheers!

edit:

So this is my main tex file

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{graphicsx} 
\begin{document}  

\section{the text}
text text text \ref{justafig} more text \ref{asecondfig}

\section{the figures}

\input{figures}

\end{document}
```

then this is figures.tex

```
\begin{figure}[tbp]%one column 
    \centering{
        \includegraphics[width=160mm]{./figa.png}} 
        \caption{the caption}
        \label{asecondfig}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[tbp]%one column 
    \centering{
        \includegraphics[width=160mm]{./figb.png}} 
        \caption{the caption}
        \label{justafig}
\end{figure}
```

But this inserts the figures in the order then are in figures.tex and I want them in the order they are cited in the text

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) The magic word is **MWE** -- Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: If you cite (`\ref`?) a figure, it has a definite counter value (say *Figure 10*). If this your first figure cited, it will become *Figure 1* effectively, is that correct? How do you track, which figure is cited first?

Comment: You missed `\usepackage{graphicx}` (or in this case better `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}` in your `main.tex` And remove the`\figure` command in your `figures.tex`

Comment: Oh yeah, they're just typos I have/don't have those in the actual source I'm using

Comment: While thinking about your question, I asked myself: How to reorder figure environments in a file? ;-)

Comment: why not just put each figure in a separate file, then call them in when desired?  it's a lot easier to reorder `figure` or `\includegraphics` commands than detailed figure code.  or it might be possible to devise a mechanism to collect the file references in order, close the list and convert that into a looping command to call in the figures in order at the end of the section/chapter.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: That's what I wanted to point to with my previous comment

Comment: So I've done that too, but then I _have_ to have all my figures at the end, so I just end up with a load of `\input{figofaclown}` in my final section. Can I call them after a paragraph but them get that figure to appear in the section I pick? (the final section of a chapter)

Comment: you might take a look at the command `\FloatBarrier`.  you'd need to divide up the calls for figures into appropriate sections, and keep figures for each section before the barrier that ends the section, but i think that should be doable.

Comment: I've had a look into it some more and I think `\Endfloat` should do what I want, I just need to work out how to get it to not actually put figures right at the end.

Comment: This answer, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/216386/flexible-inclusion-of-floating-environments-from-external-files/216397#216397, shows how to define figures in one order, yet include them in your document in another order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a tex file for each figures details and insert using `\input{figdetails}` at the correct point in the text.

Add the package [`endfloat`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/endfloat) at the start of the document.